# Cordova PushPlugin "App in Background" execute javascript CallBack

Tags: android, cordova, notifications, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework

I have tried official PushPlugin and other forks as well. The only issue I face is when we receive multiple push notifications (app in background / stop state). In that case we have to explicitly click on the notification to open the app (which is in background / stop) state. 
What happens is we do receive payload related to the notification we clicked.

1. I want to get the notification processed by my javascript callback as soon as it arrives. Is it possible ?
2. Even if I click one notification, I only get reference to it only, not for other notifications. Moreover Clicking the home button wipes of all notifications from Status Bar (I loose Notification in this case).

The problem would be easily solved, if
1. We have a javascript callback being executed as soon as the notification arrives.
2. On Clicking individual Notification from status bar, we should be able to get all the notifications which still exists in tray.

I have forked from pull request from 
https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/pull/333
and tried playing around the code, but things are not up to the expectation.

Answer (score 0):

In my chat app. I use push notification together with signalr to acheive your purpose.

when there is a new message sent by user x to user y, when signalr Server get the message from x, it stored the message in sql.

At this point of time, user Y may be in one of the following case:

Case 1: user Y is on-line and in the foreground and is already chatting with X, then SignalR server call a javascript function of user Y to update Y's display, so that Y can see the message immediately and hear a sound.

Case 2: user Y is on-line but in the background (or user Y is in the foreground but not in the screen that chat with x, for example, Y is chatting with Z), then
SignalR server call a javascript function of user Y to update Y's display, then use Push Notification to send a notification to Y and play another sound, so that when Y see the notification, click it, Y can see the new message.

Case 3: user Y is off-line or user Y close the app, then
SignalR server do nothing (nothing can be done since Y is not connected).  Push Notification do nothing.  However, when user Y is on-line again, it read from the server if there is any new messages pending.

Comment: Kenneth Li,
Thanks for your reply, but I wanted my push notifications to carry msg with them, rather then app upon opening sending a call again to the server to fetch message.

I want behaviour similar to whatsapp, in which even if after receiving notification the mobile goes offline, the app should be able to get msg from push notification sent before.

Comment: Hi Ritvick,  Sorry that I did not explain the answer clear enough since I was using a mobile phone to answer.  I am exactly working on a Whatsapp like app.  The message contains text, or text + images (you know, the emoji) just like Whatsapp.  Pls. take a look at my updated answer.